# Echarts line chart. Event on click line

Tags: javascript, echarts

How can I fire event on click line (not dots) on line chart using Echarts.

This code fires only if I click the dot on chart

```
myChart.on('mouseup', function (params) {
  console.log(params);
});
```

Do you now any other library where it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to add to `triggerLineEvent: true` in series

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line',
      triggerLineEvent: true,
    },
    {
      data: [0, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line',
      triggerLineEvent: true,
    }
  ]
};

myChart.on('click', function (params) {
    console.log(params);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**ECharts** doesn't provide a built-in event for clicking on a line itself in a chart. The interaction events are usually associated with dots on the chart.

You have basically two options. You can do a workaround by adding invisible data points along the line at regular intervals and then binding click events to those invisible data points. This would create an illusion of clicking the line itself. Or you can switch to a totally different library. **D3.js** is a highly flexible library that allows you to create custom visualizations with more control over events. However, it also has a steeper learning curve compared to libraries like **ECharts**.

Edit:
Here is also my most minimal example of how you could achieve this with D3.js
https://jsfiddle.net/kwbfxjau/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="chart" width="400" height="300"></svg>
  <script>

    const data = [
      { x: 0, y: 5 },
      { x: 1, y: 9 },
    ];

    const svg = d3.select("#chart");
    const width = +svg.attr("width");
    const height = +svg.attr("height");

    // Define scales
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.x)])
      .range([0, width]);

    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.y)])
      .range([height, 0]);

    // Define line generator
    const line = d3.line()
      .x(d => xScale(d.x))
      .y(d => yScale(d.y));

    // Append line to the SVG
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "red")
      .attr("stroke-width", 8)
      .attr("d", line)
      .on("click", handleLineClick);

    function handleLineClick(event) {
      console.log("Line clicked!");
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have example, how I can handle event on line using D3.js ?

Comment: There are plenty on the internet for example this one https://jsfiddle.net/b8rzvtwg/1/

Comment: its from line 46 to line 55

Comment: please make it like answer with code example of simple  line chart and event on line/ Will mark as answer

Comment: I have created a simpler example with a simple red line. Please also upvote :3

Comment: found than it is possible with echarts - https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-line.triggerLineEvent
and my own answer